# How to generate html file to give download link to manifest.plist file in order to install ipa to iphone

Tags: shell, jenkins, ad-hoc-distribution

I have used jenkins to build by xcode iphone project using xcbuild packageApplication by giving its global path to jenkins.Use provisional profile including device UDID.It is generating ipa file successfully but how can we distribute it using html file in jenkins.I have written a shell script to generate manifest and other jenkins setup and it is working fine.My code is as follows:-

setting up build _ parameterized

[image]

setting up post build actions in jenkins configuration.
[image]

```
#!/bin/sh

function fail {
    echo "$*" >&2
    exit 1
}

function section_print {
    echo "\n=== $* ==="
}

section_print "Building $CONFIGURATION";

if [ -z $CONFIGURATION ]; then
    fail "No configuration specified";
    exit 1;
fi

#strange way to force backslash

if [ $PROJDIR ]; then
    PROJDIR=${PROJDIR%/}
    PROJDIR="$PROJDIR/"
    section_print "Project Dir is specified and is $PROJDIR"
    cd "$PROJDIR" || fail "no directory $PROJDIR"
    pwd
fi

section_print "Unlocking keychain"
security unlock-keychain -p "password" ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain

section_print "Cleaning build"
xcodebuild -configuration "$CONFIGURATION" clean || fail "Clean failed"

section_print "Building $CONFIGURATION"

xcodebuild -configuration "$CONFIGURATION"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk || fail "Build failed"

section_print "Packaging ipa"

BUILD_PATH=build/"$CONFIGURATION"-iphoneos

#we are already in the $PROJDIR

cd "$BUILD_PATH" || fail "no directory 'build/$CONFIGURATION-iphoneos'"

for file in "*.app"
do
    APP_NAME=`echo $file`
done

APP_NAME=${APP_NAME%.*}

section_print "Removing old artefacts"

cd "$WORKSPACE"

rm -f *.ipa
rm -f *.dSYM.zip
rm -f *.mobileprovision

#take $PROJDIR into account

section_print "Application name $APP_NAME"

cd "$PROJDIR$BUILD_PATH"

rm -rf Payload
rm -f "$APP_NAME".*.ipa
mkdir Payload

cp -Rp "$APP_NAME.app" Payload/

if [ -f "$WORKSPACE"/iTunesArtwork ]; then

    cp -f "$WORKSPACE"/iTunesArtwork Payload/iTunesArtwork

fi

IPA_FILE="$APP_NAME.$BUILD_ID.$BUILD_NUMBER.ipa"
zip -r "$IPA_FILE" Payload

section_print "Compressing dSYM"

rm -f "*.dSYM.zip"
DSYM_FILE="$APP_NAME.$BUILD_ID.$BUILD_NUMBER.dSYM.zip"
zip -r "$DSYM_FILE" "$APP_NAME.app.dSYM"

section_print "Exporting profile"

cp -f "$APP_NAME.app/embedded.mobileprovision" profile.mobileprovision

section_print "Get the profile name"

PROFILE_NAME=`strings ./profile.mobileprovision | grep -A1 '<key>Name</key>' | tail -n1 | awk -F'<string>' '{print $2}' | awk -F'</string>' '{print $1}'`
PROFILE_NAME=${PROFILE_NAME//'*'/}
PROFILE_NAME=${PROFILE_NAME//'?'/}
PROFILE_NAME="$PROFILE_NAME.mobileprovision"

section_print "Profile name is $PROFILE_NAME"

mv -f "profile.mobileprovision" "$PROFILE_NAME"
rm -f "$WORKSPACE/*.mobileprobision" || fail "Failed to remove $WORKSPACE/*.mobileprovision"
rm -f "$WORKSPACE/$IPA_FILE" || fail "Failed to remove $WORKSPACE/$IPA_FILE"

section_print "Copying $IPA_FILE to artifacts"
cp -v "$IPA_FILE" "$WORKSPACE/." || fail "Failed to copy ipa"
cp -v "$PROFILE_NAME" "$WORKSPACE/." || fail "Failed to copy profile"
cp -v "$DSYM_FILE" "$WORKSPACE/." || fail "Failed to copy dSYM"
section_print "Build succeeded"

#creating manifest.plist file to download ipa file

if [ -d "${WORKSPACE}/$JOB_NAME" ]; then

  rm -r ${WORKSPACE}/$JOB_NAME

fi

mkdir ${WORKSPACE}/$JOB_NAME

cp $WORKSPACE/icon.png ${WORKSPACE}/$JOB_NAME/Icon-57.png
cp $WORKSPACE/icon@2x.png ${WORKSPACE}/$JOB_NAME/Icon-512.png

TARGET_NAME=$APP_NAME

info_plist=$(ls ${WORKSPACE}/*/*-Info.plist)

bundle_version=$(defaults read $info_plist CFBundleShortVersionString)
bundle_id=$(defaults read $info_plist CFBundleIdentifier)

cat << EOF > ${WORKSPACE}/manifest2.plist

<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0" mimeType="application/xml">

<dict>
   <key>items</key>
   <array>
       <dict>
           <key>assets</key>
           <array>
               <dict>
                   <key>kind</key>
                   <string>software-package</string>
                   <key>url</key>
                   <string>http://192.168.0.237:8080/job/$JOB_NAME/ws/$IPA_FILE</string>
               </dict>
               <dict>
                   <key>kind</key>
                   <string>display-image</string>
                   <key>needs-shine</key>
                   <true/>
                   <key>url</key>
                   <string>${WORKSPACE}/$JOB_NAME/Icon-57.png</string>
               </dict>
               <dict>
                   <key>kind</key>
                   <string>full-size-image</string>
                   <key>needs-shine</key>
                   <true/>
                   <key>url</key>
                   <string>${WORKSPACE}/$JOB_NAME/Icon-512.png</string>
               </dict>
           </array>
           <key>metadata</key>
           <dict>
               <key>bundle-identifier</key>
               <string>$bundle_id</string>
               <key>bundle-version</key>
               <string>$bundle_version #$BUILD_NUMBER</string>
               <key>kind</key>
               <string>software</string>
               <key>title</key>
               <string>$APP_NAME</string>
           </dict>
       </dict>
   </array>
</dict>
</plist>

EOF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

append code to create html file in shell script

```
cat << EOF > ${WORKSPACE}/download.html
<html>
<body>
<h1>Download IPA Here</h1>
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://192.168.0.237:8080/job/$JOB_NAME/ws/manifest2.plist" mimeType="application/octet-stream">
    <b>Install App</b>
</a>
</body>
</html>
EOF
```

and some changes to publish action show download file on artifacts.

[image]